# Excel 2016 VBA activeworkbook actions are not done on activeworkbook once we change to thisworkbook

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I'm trying to copy data from workbook where macro code is written to a new workbook and renaming the sheet. Code works fine in 2013 but same code throws error in windows 10 2016.

```
Below is the sample code (made changes)

Sub test()
Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "This workbook"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set newwb = Workbooks.Add
Worksheets.Add
Worksheets.Add
For i = 0 To 50

newwb.Activate
Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "activeworkbook workbook"
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "test"
newwb.Activate   '--> I don't need to add this code but just to check if it works and still the same issue. 
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Name = "test2"
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Name = "test3"
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "This workbook"
Next

End Sub
Can you say why it is throwing the error?
Code works perfectly fine in windows 7 excel 2013 but same code throws error in 2016.

It would be great if anyone can help me with this issue.
```

Comment: what error? Also I would recommend to avoid using `ActiveWorkbook`. Instead use `newwb`, you already have the reference it's no need to activate the workbook to complete the action.

Comment: It says sheet name already used as it refers to thiswrokbook. When I tried to change the sheet name it refers to thisworkbook instead of activeworkbook. Not sure why this happens but it works fine in 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use direct referencing and avoid ActiveWorkbook. Also you should Dim variables before you use them...

```
Sub test()
    On Error GoTo ExitSub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim newwb As Workbook: Set newwb = Workbooks.Add
    newwb.Worksheets.Add
    newwb.Worksheets.Add

    Dim i As Long

    ThisWorkbook.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "This workbook"

    With newwb
        For i = 0 To 50
            .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "activeworkbook workbook"
            .Sheets(1).Name = "test"
            .Sheets(2).Name = "test2"
            .Sheets(3).Name = "test3"
            ThisWorkbook.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "This workbook"
        Next i
    End With

ExitSub:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Flephal, Thank you for reply. Code which I provided is a sample works in 2013 but not in 2016. can you say why it is happening? activeworkbook works fine in 2013 but not in 2016.